# LinearLayout dynamically display depending on a given number

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I want to create a method that can dynamically display `LinearLayout` in a `LinearLayout` also that is located in a specified area in my Android application, the number of this linear layout changes depending on a given number.

Also, in each `LinearLayout` I want to display a `Button` and below it a `TextView`.

**Here is the method I have already created:**

```
public void putLinearLayout(double number){

       int mButtonHeight = 100;
        int mButtonWidth = 80;
         LinearLayout Linear = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearlayout1);

        for(int i=1;i<=number;i++)
        {
            LinearLayout L = new LinearLayout(this);


            Button b= new Button(this);
            TextView tv = new TextView(this);
            L.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
            b.setWidth(mButtonWidth);
            b.setHeight(mButtonHeight);
            L.addView(b);
            L.addView(tv);
            Linear.addView(L);
        }

    }
```

Comment: what is the problem with it?

Comment: did you add text to the button and textview ?

Comment: also my problem is how to put the button and the text view on this linear layout

Comment: No, i didn't add text to the button and textview, how can i do it !!

Comment: Please describe your problem better, so we can help you. What is the problem? What is not working? What is the result you get?

Comment: This method doesn't work, my problem is how to put the button and the text view on this linear layout

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you just need to set the layoutparams

```
public void putLinearLayout(double number){
        LinearLayout Linear = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearlayout1);
               int mButtonHeight = 100;
                int mButtonWidth = 80;

                for(int i=1;i<=number;i++)
                {
                    LinearLayout L = new LinearLayout(this);
                    L.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                    LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT); //<--this line , is what you were missing
                    L.setLayoutParams(params); //<-- and then this
                    Button b= new Button(this);
                    b.setText(i+"");
                    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
                    tv.setText("i am textview number: "+i);
                    L.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
                    b.setWidth(mButtonWidth);
                    b.setHeight(mButtonHeight);
                    L.addView(b);
                    L.addView(tv);
                    Linear .addView(L);
                }
```

}

Comment: Thanks, this is what I want but not exactly

Comment: I want to create a method that can load an image stored in my sqlite database.
In my database i created a table that contains the image adress and the image identifiant, my goal is to put each image on button already created
  
    public String getImage(int i)//afficher une image 
    {
     String res;
     SQLiteStatement s = database.compileStatement ("SELECT " + COL_ADRESS_IMAGE + "FROM " + TABLE_IMAGE + "WHERE id_image IN (SELECT " + COL_IMAGE_CATEGORY +
       "FROM " + TABLE_CATEGORY + "WHERE " + COL_ID_CATEGORY + "= '" +i +"')" );
     res = s.toString();
     return res;
    }

Comment: you don't know how to put image on button ?

Comment: I want to put an image from my database on button

Comment: is your image a blob or a url ?

Comment: is the image downloaded to the device upon button click ? can you be more elaborate?

Comment: No, I want the image on the button

Comment: do you get the image on the device? only an image that was downloaded on the device can be displayed on the button

Comment: how I can download this image on the device
I'm  really stuck, i don't know how can i do this :(

Answer (score 0):

i use it to draw table row :

```
public void createTableRow(String textBoxContent,Integer catId) {
      TableLayout tl = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.SelectCat);
      TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
      LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
      tr.setLayoutParams(lp);
      tr.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);

      Button btnLeft = new Button(this);
      btnLeft.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(0,android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,(float) 0.5));
      btnLeft.setText(R.string.Show);
      btnLeft.setTag(catId);
      TextView tvCenter = new TextView(this);
      tvCenter.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f));
      tvCenter.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
      tvCenter.setText(textBoxContent);

      tr.addView(btnLeft);
      tr.addView(tvCenter);

      tl.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    }
```

it's simple to change to linear layout
if you have a problem, i can guide you more

Comment: I have another problem,I want to put an image from my database on button, can you help me

Comment: read the image and put into byt array,then insert the array in database,and in load get the byte array and convert to bitmap,this is another question and you must ask it again on another post@Sally

Comment: Can you explain me more about the load of image